# My CodePlex project doesn't show up on my Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'd like to add a CodePlex project to my Careers 2.0 profile.
The CodePlex site accepts my login, confirms my identity, but does not show any project.
I'm not the owner of the project, just a developer.

Is it a bug or a feature? (Are owners the only ones that can add their projects?)

Comment: I'm the co-ordinator on a project that doesn't show, so it's not just you, nor the contributor level.

Comment: Seems to be working again (for me at least)

Comment: I think what you were experiencing was a more general bug (the Codeplex API changed on us). Try it again?

Comment: I have a similar problem, once authorized, the "Import CodePlex" page says "We found the following projects for" then something that looks like Json about my CodePlex profile but no option to select my projets :(

Comment: I have the same problem, still doesn't work for me. I'm the coordinator of one project on CodePlex and it doesn't show up.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This seems broken again.... I get the response with some JSON of my profile but cannot select any projects.

Comment: I passed this on to the Careers dev team. Thanks for the heads up!